# Pressing shift and click multiple times in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

How to keep shift all the time and click in react testing library

I have tried this but it didn't work

```js
const layerElement = screen.getByText("Layer one");
fireEvent.click(layerElement, { shiftKey: true });

const groupElement = screen.getByText("Group 1");
fireEvent.click(groupElement, { shiftKey: true });

fireEvent.contextMenu(groupElement, { shiftKey: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried that myself yet but I'm almost certain you can achieve that bu using the latest `userEvent` api. It's a supplement library to RTL that better simulates user interactions instead of just firing abstract user events so generally it is recommended to be used over the `fireEvent` api. You can read about the `userEvent` api and how to install and set it up [**here**](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro)

Afterwards, you should be able to use a combination of `user.keyboard` and `user.click` to achieve youe goal.

From the **[docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/keyboard)** - `user.keyboard` allows you to simulate a key press without releasing it:

> "Keys can be kept pressed by adding a > to the end of the descriptor.
> If this should result in repeated keydown events, you can add the
> number of repetitions. If the key should also be released after this,
> add a slash / to the end of the descriptor."
>
> ```
> keyboard('{a>}') // press "a" without releasing it
> keyboard('{a>5}') // press "a" without releasing it and trigger 5 keydown
> keyboard('{a>5/}') // press "a" for 5 keydown and then release it
> ```
>
> A previously pressed key can be lifted by prefixing the descriptor
> with /.
>
> ```
> keyboard('{/a}') // release a previously pressed a
> ```

So I think you **should** be able to do something like:

```
user.keyboard("{Shift>}");
user.click(component);
user.keyboard("{/Shift}");
```